# How to resolve the cmake error while compiling stage

Tags: fltk, player-stage

On compiling stage .. i.e cmake section, I'm getting this error, which I'm not able to resolve
FYI : player and stage are the latest versions.

```
-- Stage version 3.2.2
-- Operating system is Linux
-- Build type RELEASE
-- Checking for libtool
-- Checking for required libraries...
--   * FLTK version 1.3.0 detected via /usr/bin/fltk-config
-- Checking for optional libraries...
--   * Player version 3.0.2 detected at /usr/local
-- checking for one of the modules 'websim'
  * WebSim not detected.
-- Installation path CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local
-- Configuring libstage
-- Configuring libstageplugin
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LTDL_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/libstage
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/examples
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/examples/ctrl
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/assets
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/worlds
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/worlds/benchmark
   used as include directory in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/libstageplugin
LTDL_LIB
    linked by target "stage" in directory /home/ravi/Desktop/AI/Stage-3.2.2-Source/libstage

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 1):

For Player/Stage you need these followings librarys which are available in general repositories:

Player:

```
cmake (2.6.4-1ubuntu2)
cmake-curses-gui (2.6.4-1ubuntu2)
libtool (2.2.6a-4)
libfltk1.1-dev (1.1.9-6ubuntu2)
libglu1-mesa-dev (7.6.0-1ubuntu4)
libboost-thread1.40-dev
libboost-signals1.40-dev
libcv1 libcv-dev (for supporting opencv)
libgnomecanvasmm-2.6-dev (for playernav)
libgsl0-dev (scientific library)
libxmu-dev (for X11)
swig
```

Stage:

```
freeglut3-dev (OpenGL)
libgtk2.0-dev
libltdl7-dev
libpng12-0-dev
```

Have you forget to configurate befor building by using ccmake?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `libtool` installed, it seems. It is strange that you do not have it on Linux (many applications depend on it).
So, first check if you have `libtool`. If you do, then simply re-configure your CMake and try again, if not, install it, and re-configure CMake project.